# How can I escape '/' in build-number for jfrog cli promote build command?

Tags: jfrog-cli

When I run a promotion on a build with a complex build number, the cli seems to view the '/' as a break resulting in failure to find the build

- jf cli version: **2.51.1**
- build name: `lib-systest`
- build number: `feature/JIRA_ID-1`
- format: branch-jenkinsBuildNo

## Command:

```
jf rt bpr "lib-systest" "feature/JIRA_ID-1" \ 
  maven-release-local \
  --source-repo maven-dev-virtual \
  --status "Released" \
  --copy
```

## Result:

```
[Info] Promoting build...
[Error] server response: 404
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "status": 404,
      "message": "Cannot find builds by the name 'lib-systest/feature' 
                  and the number 'JIRA_ID-1' and buildRepo 'artifactory-build-info'."
    }
  ]
}
```

- name is not `lib-systest/feature` but `lib-systest`
- number is not `JIRA_ID-1` but `feature/JIRA_ID-1`

### Attempts

I've tried the following escaping approaches and none seem to work

- `"feature\/JIRA_ID-1"`
- `"feature\\/JIRA_ID-1"`
- `"feature%2FJIRA_ID-1"`
- `"feature :: JIRA_ID-1"`

I've opened a support ticket and I'm hoping someone else had this issue and found a workaround.

### Workaround options

- change the naming convention to never use '/' in a version `.replaceAll('/', '-') - that would required touching 1000s of repositories for me.
- write a python script REST replacement for the `jf rt bpr` command as then I'll have control over promotion args
- find an aql way to execute a promotion as AQL filters can handle '/' in the number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At present, Jfrog has what I believe is a bug (see https://github.com/jfrog/jfrog-cli/issues/2330)

But, it is easy to work around the problem with

- a promotion.json
- a curl call

### Jenkins Shared Library Excerpt

The following is groovy code.

- writeJson transforms the Map into a json file
- steps.sh executes a shell script with hiding potential secrets should CredentialsBinding not quite do it.

```
// Generate Payload
def payload = [
        'status': "Released",
        'ciUser': 'jenkins',
        'dryRun': false,
        'targetRepo': "gradle-release-local",
        /* equivalent to `--copy` from jf rt bpr */
        'artifacts': true,
        'dependencies': true
]
jsonHandler.writeJson(payload, 'payload.json')

// Call API via curl
steps.sh(script: """
    set +x
    curl \
        -H "Authorization: Bearer ${IdentityToken}" \
        -H "Content-type:application/json" \
        --data-binary @promote.json \
        -X POST "${artifactoryServerUrl}/api/build/promote/lib-systest/feature%2FJIRA_ID-1"
    set -x
""", returnStdout: true).trim()
```

The `-X POST "url"` handles URL escaping properly